# ModernCV vertical alignment of symbols in cv title

Tags: vertical-alignment, moderncv

I want to make symbols centered with text.
The image shows my problem.

How can I center symbols?
[image: Not Centered Symbol Problem]

Comment: Do you mean that you want to center them *vertically*?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: I've added the [tag:vertical-alignment] tag to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The added code will lower the three symbols, aligning them with the text.

The symbols are lowered using `\raisebox{<distance>}{<content>}` with a negative `distance`.

[image: x]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex    

\documentclass[a4paper]{moderncv}
    
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{burgundy}                          

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\name{Emin}{Umut Gerçek}
\phone[mobile]{(1)~234~567~890}        
\email{mail@mail.com}  
\social[github]{eugercek}

% ********************************* added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   
\newbox{\phantombox}
\sbox{\phantombox}{\small (}    
\renewcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}{\raisebox{-0.5\dp\phantombox}{\small\faMobile*~}}
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}{\raisebox{-0.5\dp\phantombox}{\small\faEnvelope[regular]~}}
\renewcommand*{\githubsocialsymbol}{\raisebox{-0.5\dp\phantombox}{\small\faGithub~}}
 %**********************************************     

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

The vertical position of any symbol can be adjusted using, for example,

```
\renewcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}{\raisebox{-0.3\dp\phantombox}{\small\faMobile*~}}
```

will move the symbol  phone up a bit to compensate for the taller numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I don't why but your snippet doesn't work same on mine, probably version thing. I removed `*` from `faMobile` and `[regular]` from `faEnvelope`. Then It worked. This is the last version. https://pastebin.com/jhjuLnGg

Comment: @Umut Gerçek  Thank you for your feedback!  Do you want me to incorporate your code as an update to my answer to help other readers?

Comment: Sorry for the very late response I thought I replied to you, If it makes your answer better for others please do it. Thanks again.